# Drawing a polyline on a predefined route from KML File between two markers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I have used GeoXml3 parser to parse KML file on google maps where i have markers and a predefined route between the markers which appears in grey colour. Now my requirement is to draw a polyline when i click on the markers on the route which is already defined from KML File. Can this be achieved?. Please take a look on the code that i have tried. I downloaded the kml file from [this](http://openflights.org/blog/2009/02/23/give-your-flights-a-spin-in-3d-on-google-earth/) link which has a sample kml to be downloaded which has predefined routes between markers. The code below helps me load a kml file. But how do i draw a polyline route on a existing route that i get from a kml file?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Draw routes over kml layer</title>
<link href="/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet"      type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"   src="http://geoxml3.googlecode.com/svn/branches/polys/geoxml3.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() 
{
var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(75.602836700999987,32.261890444473394);
var myOptions = {
zoom: 2,
center: chicago,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP }

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
//var transitLayer = new google.maps.TransitLayer();   
//transitLayer.setMap(map);
   var geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({map: map, singleInfoWindow: true});
   geoXml.parse('flights.kml'); 

   }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
 <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I require to draw route over the route as displayed in the image.[image: This]

Comment: Borrowing from [marcelo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/408519/marcelo): Motto2: Everything is possible, you just have to code it.  What does your KML look like?  What does your existing code look like?  What have you tried?

Comment: Geocodezip : If you can please guide me to a proper path?. I have not ever done anything as such. What i have acheived is i have parsed a kml file on google maps.

Comment: Geocodezip: Edited my question.I have added the code that i have tried and also the link for the kml file that i downloaded and using it.

Comment: OK.  So you have this: http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_SO_geoxmlPolylines.html What functionality are you attempting to add?  That KML file has one huge MultiGeometry containing all the "flights" (the polylines), and a bunch of Placemarks for the airports.  That will make it difficult to do what it sounds like you want to do.  I suggest breaking each flight path into its own Placemark, that will allow you to control each path separately.

Comment: Geocodezip: Rite..This is what i have actually loaded. Now you can find routes that have been drawn between many markers.Now when i click on any two markers, the route should be drawn on the existing route that is getting displayed from KML File... I know to draw routes using DirectionService but this will not help here..:(

Comment: These are the separately controllable Placemarks in your file (listed in the sidebar): http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/openflights-sample.kml

Comment: Ok..They are just a part of information for the users and its not possible to draw routes on a kml route...Is there any other alternative that i can try?

Comment: What do you mean "it is not possible to draw routes on a kml route"?

Comment: I am drawing routes by making use of direction service when i click on two markers. that creates a polyline in between the markers irrespective of (DRIVING, TRANSIT,WALKING) that is mentioned. But is it possible to create a route on the placemarks that is visible on the kml file when i select markers on the kml file in the map????

Comment: GeocodeZip: I have edited my question and added a image which shows my exact requirement of drawing route.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "route".  What I think you want to do is: 1. separate all the polylines (called LineString in KML) out of the KML 2. name them appropriately (i.e. with the names of the two endpoint airports) 3. display the appropriate polyline when your code receives clicks on two of the markers.

Comment: Geocodezip: Rite..Exactly what i want to do....

Comment: So... What have you done to accomplish that?  Or is that the answer to your question?

Comment: Geocodezip: I tried using Direction Service on click of markers..Yes it creates polylines but they are either driving, transit or walking between the markers..:(..Yes your comment is the answer to my query but i am not sure how do i accomplish what you have mentioned in the comment..

Comment: Why would you use the directions service when you already have the polylines you want in your KML?  I don't have time to code it for you right now.  Here is [an example with the KML with the polylines broken out of the MultiGeometry](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/openflights-sampleA.kml)

Comment: Thanks a lot...:-)..I accept the above comment as the answer to my question...

Comment: Added a second option which doesn't require naming the polylines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- separate all the polylines (called LineString in KML) out of the KML

[example that breaks the polylines out of the MultiGeometry](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/openflights-sampleA.kml)

- name them appropriately (i.e. with the names of the two endpoint airports)
- display the appropriate polyline when your code receives clicks on two of the markers.

**Second option (more technically interesting and computationally intensive):**

- separate out the polylines as above
- in a click listener for the markers

  1. for the first marker, find all the lines that terminate at that marker and display them (hiding all the others)
  2. for the second marker, find the line (if any) that terminates at both markers, display it, hiding all others, clear the state so you can start again.

[proof of concept](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_SO_geoxmlPolylinesB.html)

Comment: Thanks a ton...It works Amazing..Thanks for sharing Geocodezip.:-)

Comment: It is far from complete (at least what I would consider complete).  It is a proof of concept, I'm sure you will find things that don't work the way you would like.  Please share your "finished" version and any of those "issues" you fixed.

Comment: Sure Geocodezip.. I am working on the model you have provided and will share my work once i am done..:-)